# Almost no pressure in sprinkler system, slight vibration in pipes

Tags: water, sprinkler-system, irrigation

I just started setting up the sprinkler systems in a new house that I'm renting. The pressure in one of the systems is almost nonexistent, and the pipes that run to the irrigation system vibrate very slightly when the system is on.

The part that vibrates is the marked part in the photo below.

Any thoughts on what I need to do to get the pressure back? I've tried rotating the valve to the left of the circled part, and that shuts off all pressure. Same with the one below.
[image]